# Behavior of max() with string parameters?

Tags: python

1. `maximum = max(1, 1.25, 3.14, 'a', 1000)` - why is it giving `'a'` as the answer? Shouldn't `'a'` get converted to ASCII and be checked?
2. `maximum = max(1, 2.15, "hello")` gives `"hello"` as answer. How does this answer come?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) -

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address

Hence `str` is always greater than `int` .

Some more examples -

```
>>> class test:
...     pass
... 
>>> t = test()
>>> 'a' > 5
True
>>> t > 'a'
False
>>> type(t)
<type 'instance'>
>>> t > 10
False
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
>>> True > 100
False
>>> False > 100
False
```

Please note the type name of `test` class' object is `instance` that is why `t > 5` is `False` .

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes `str` greater than `int`? It isn't alphabetical so how do they order the type names?

Comment: @2016rshah what has brought you to the conclusion that `'str' > 'int'` **isn't** alphabetical?

Comment: They are alphaetical, where did you see its not alphabetical? For object of a custom class, the type is `instance` .

Comment: Oh wait never mind I am not entirely sure what brought me to that conclusion. Silly mistake, sorry. Should I delete my comment?

Answer (score 8):

Because strings in Python 2 are always greater than numbers.

```
>>> "a" > 1000
True
```

In Python3 it's actually *fixed*, they are incomparable now (because there is actually no way to compare 42 and "dog").